# Print the output of os.system to the screen and take actions based upon it

Tags: python, io

I've got a Python script that uses os.system to run shell commands. The output from those commands is echoed to the screen; I like this and need to keep it. I would also like my script to be able to take action based on the contents of the output from the system call. How can I do this?

In my specific case, I'm calling `os.system("svn update")`. I need the output to go to the screen and (in case of conflicts, for example), *the user needs to be able to interact with svn*. I would like to be able to have the script take action based on the output - to trigger a build if it sees that a build script was updated, for example.

I'd prefer not to handle the I/O myself (that would seem unnecessarily complex) and I'd rather not send the output to a temporary file that I have to clean up later (though I will if I must).

Edit:

Here's my test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -t

import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["echo","one"])
print "python:", output

output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "two"], shell=True)
print "python:", output

output = subprocess.check_output("echo three", shell=True)
print "python:", output
```

and here's its output:

```
$ ./pytest 
python: one

python: 

python: three
```

(There's an extra blank line at the end that the code block doesn't show.) I expect something more like:

```
$ ./pytest 
one
python: one
two
python: 
three
python: three
```

Comment: You can't with `os.system`.  You'll need to use `subprocess` ... and even then these things can get tricky.  Is it Ok to wait to take an action after `svn update` has run, or do you actually need to interact with the process as it is running?

Comment: @mgilson The user will need to interact with the process (to make decisions as to how the conflict should be resolved). The script will not need to interact with the process - it just needs to grep the output for a specific string or regex.

Comment: Does this need to be a cross-platform solution, or would a Linux-only solution be acceptable?

Comment: @SamMussmann Doesn't need to be cross-platform, but I'm on a Mac. (So most Linux-only solutions should work, or be adaptable.)

Comment: I had an idea about using `os.forkpty()` and `os.execvp()`, but I can't seem to make it work at the moment.  If I get some more time to look at it and get it working, I'll let you know...

Answer (score 2):

To run a process, I would look into [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).  In this case, something like:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['svn','update'])
print output
```

This only works on python2.7 or newer though.  If you want a version which works with older versions of python:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['svn','update'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output,stderr = p.communicate()
print output
```

Comment: I'm on python 2.7, so I tried the subprocess version (both `subprocess.check_output(["echo","one"])` and `subprocess.check_output(["echo", "two"], shell=True)`), but neither print anything to the shell. Also, the former returns "one" (as expected), but the latter doesn't return "two").

Comment: I think with `shell=True`, the program to run should be a single string, much like you would give the shell as input when you run it interactively.  Try `subprocess.check_output("echo two", shell=True)`?  Can you use `print` to show the output in the shell?

Comment: @SamMussmann I'll edit the question with my test script and its output. Indeed, it does appear that shell=True won't let you use a command arg list.

Comment: @CajunLuke -- Sorry.  Once you have the output stored as a variable in python, you can simply print the output to get the data to appear on the console -- e.g. `print output`.

Comment: @mgilson But then the user wouldn't be able to interact with the svn update command when there's conflicts.

Comment: @CajunLuke -- But you said that you don't need to interact with the process: "The script will not need to interact with the process"

Comment: @mgilson The script doesn't, but the *user* does. (Italicized section in question for emphasis.)

Comment: @CajunLuke -- Yes, I see.  Perhaps this is just semantics here, but your script does need to interact with `svn` -- even if it is via user input.  Anyway, you can forget using `Popen.communicate` (or `check_output`) because that waits for the process to complete before returning.  You'll probably need an `pexpect` like library to tell you if `Popen.stdout` has data and then to get a handle on that data.  But, now we're well into uncharted territory for me, so I'm afraid I can't be too much additional help.